# Dll de .Net con Web Service en VB6

Tags: vb.net, .net, webservice, vb6

planteo el siguiente escenario.

- Tengo una DLL (***desarrollado en .Net con fwrk 4***) donde una de
  sus funciones es conectarse a un WebService (Referencia de servicio).
- Tengo algunos proyectos desarrollados en .Net que consumen dicha DLL.
- Tengo algunos proyectos desarrollados en Vb6 que necesitan consumir
  esa DLL.

Los proyectos desarrollados en .Net funcionan sin problemas usando la referencia de la Dll.
Pero tengo problemas al usarla en los proyectos de vb6.

La DLL ya la pude referenciar en el VB6 y puedo invocar los métodos existentes, pero me da el siguiente error al tratar de ejecutar los métodos del webservice.

[image: Este es el error que muestra]

Este error lo tuve al principio cuando agregué y probé la dll con los proyectos de .Net y la solución fue agregando el bloque de serviceModel **(binding y endpoint)** del app.config generado por el proyecto de la DLL en el app.config del proyecto donde usaba la DLL. y funcionó.

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo lo resuelvo en el VB6.?

Muchas gracias.
A la espera de sus comentarios

Comment: Realizar una respuestas correctamente en base a [answer], las respuestas que tienen únicamente enlaces no son validas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya me ayudaron con el tema.

Lo que hay que hacer es copiar el app.config generado del proyecto de la DLL y pegarlo en la carpeta del VB6 luego renombrarlo a VB6.exe.config

Tener en cuenta que cuando se compile el proyecto hay que renombrar el archivo de configuración a nombreProyecto.exe.config y estar junto a nombreProyecto.exe para su funcionamiento.

Mientras se esté usando con el IDE de vb6 el archivo debe estar junto a VB6.exe y llamarse VB6.exe.config

Fuente [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842565/dll-with-webservices-from-net-to-vb6-how-to-setup-app-config/47867724#47867724)

Comment: Genial! Podrias traducir la respuesta? mas alla del link, podes aclarar que es una traduccion de una respuesta en ingles. (Por que no todos saben leer ingles)

Comment: Realizar una respuestas correctamente en base a [answer], las respuestas que tienen únicamente enlaces no son validas.

Comment: Si gracias, ya edite la respuesta.